# how to find out what figures are used/included in a latex file

Tags: table-of-contents

I have authored several books, class notes, papers, with many figures. All figures reside in the same Windows folder named \figures because they may be used in multiple documents.

When I need to send an individual document to somebody, I'd like to zip the .tex file for that document together with the figures needed, not all figures in the \figures folder.

How can I find out **automatically** what figures (filename.ext) are used/referenced in an individual .tex document. Currently, I have to search manually to find out what figures (filenames) are needed.

Comment: What kind of figures do you use? Are they all included using `\includegraphics` or how do the documents make use of them?

Comment: Though this might be solved with TeX, i think another script language can the do the job faster and better.

Comment: Check the bundledoc package.

Comment: One could modify \includegraphics to write the filename to a new file.  The tricky bit is that filenames often use special characters, so \includegraphics doesn't use normal argument processing.

Comment: You can `grep` the log for `Package pdftex.def Info: filename.ext used on input line n` (pdflatex/lualatex, for xelatex something similar).

Answer (score 1):

Using a purely LaTeX solution you could use a wrapper around `\includegraphics` like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newwrite\figuresusedout
\immediate\openout\figuresusedout=\jobname.figs%
  
\NewDocumentCommand{\FigureUsedOut}{m}{%
  \immediate\write\figuresusedout{#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\IncludeGraphics}{ O{} m }{%
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}\FigureUsedOut{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\IncludeGraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{./figures/red.png}
\caption{Red}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[b]
\IncludeGraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{./figures/green.png}
\caption{green}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

using these images in a subdirectory called `./figures/`:

`green.png`:

[image]

`purple.png`:

[image]

`red.png`:

[image]

This produces an output file with extension `.figs` containing:

```
./figures/red.png
./figures/green.png
```

There are probably a lot of better ways to do this, including with external programmes etc and improved recent packages but this works.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `\listfiles` command as the first command of your tex file (even before the `\documentclass`), then the log file will end by listing all of the files that it used.  This will include all of the packages you loaded (and the packages they loaded, etc), but it will also include your figures.

Answer (score 1):

I am only simplifying the solution by @JamesT to be more minimal and avoid the need to change all `\includegraphics` commands...

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newwrite\graphics
\immediate\openout\graphics=\jobname.graphics%
\let\oincludegraphics\includegraphics% store original \includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{% prepend to it (could also use xpatch, etc.)
  \immediate\write\graphics{#2}
  \oincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

produces `\jobname.graphics` containing:

```
example-image-a
example-image-b
```

You can also comment out `\newwrite ... \oincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}` to remove this thing.

Comment: @JamesT since this is really your answer, perhaps consider updating yours with anything useful from mine and then I will delete mine.

Comment: +1 no its fine don't worry, I just seen this question was years old with no answers so thought I'd answer it as I learn more. I like your solution, thanks for sharing will learn from it too :)